# how to convert link list to matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

my input data looks like(input.txt)：

```
AGAP2     TCGA-BL-A0C8-01A-11R-A10U-07      66.7328
AGAP2     TCGA-BL-A13I-01A-11R-A13Y-07      186.8366
AGAP3     TCGA-BL-A13J-01A-11R-A10U-07      183.3767
AGAP3     TCGA-BL-A3JM-01A-12R-A21D-07      33.2927
AGAP3     TCGA-BT-A0S7-01A-11R-A10U-07      57.9040
AGAP3     TCGA-BT-A0YX-01A-11R-A10U-07      99.8540
AGAP4     TCGA-BT-A20J-01A-11R-A14Y-07      88.8278
AGAP4     TCGA-BT-A20N-01A-11R-A14Y-07      129.7021
```

i want the output.txt looks like :

```
        TCGA-BL-A0C8-01A-11R-A10U-07  TCGA-BL-A13I-01A-11R-A13Y-07  ...
AGAP2   66.7328                       186.8366
AGAP3   0                             0
```

Comment: i couldn't find any pattern in output.txt. How i can achieve output from input?

Comment: Do you want to convert the second column values into its own columns with values from third column?

Comment: my input data format with:
column1 be sample ,column2 be features ,column3 means the sample had feature and its value.
and i  want to column1 be sample from column1,  column2 be feature1 from clumn2, column3  be feature2 from column3,..  @Anand S Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pandas`: read csv, create pivot and write csv.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table("input.txt", names="xy", sep=r'\s+')
# reset index first - we need named column
new = df.reset_index().pivot(index="index", columns='x', values='y')
new.fillna(0, inplace=True)
new.to_csv("output.csv", sep='\t')      # tab separated
```

[image: result]

[Reshaping and Pivot Tables](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html)

**EDIT**: filling empty values

Comment: yeah,you got me,but none empty,the weight will be "0" or the "value".and i run your code,but it has some wrong:
df = pd.read_table("ALL.sort.patient.cancer.txt", names="xy", sep=r'\s+')

Comment: If you want zeros instead empty values, use `fillna`.

Comment: i got the error report：Exception: Index has duplicates: ['AGAP2', 'AKT1', @pacholik

Comment: Hard to tell without your input.

Comment: my input data format with: column1 be sample (str) ,column2 be features (str) ,column3 means the sample had feature and its value. looks like the data to the above @pacholik

Comment: There is no `'AKT1'` in the above example.

Comment: i got this report on the above example(the same problem about the duplicates)
Exception: Index has duplicates: ['AGAP2', 'AGAP3', 'AGAP4']@ pacholik

Comment: @ pacholikit ,it works ,and if  the third column in input data is  "int",what can i change in code?  like  1  2   3   4   not the float data?

Comment: pandas preservers dtypes in pivots